# Swift Package fails to compile for watchOS

Tags: swift, xctest, watchos, swift-package-manager

My Swift Package fails to compile when selecting the watchOS target.

[image]

The error message is `Failed to load module 'XCTest'` and build error details is:

`/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/WatchSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/WatchSimulator6.0.sdk/usr/lib/swift/XCTest.swiftmodule/i386.swiftinterface:6:19: XCTest is not available when building for watchOS Simulator. Consider using`#if targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)`to conditionally import this framework when building for Mac Catalyst.`

There is no XCTest in watchOS so do I get my Swift Package to compile for watchOS?

Comment: Hello @TruMan1, did you managed to find a solution ?

Comment: No it's still a problem and unfortunately wrapping all my tests with `#if !os(watchOS)`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a total hack but one way I've been getting round this during development is to temporarily comment out the `.testTarget(name:dependencies:)` type method in the Package.swift file. After that, clean the build folder, then build and run for watchOS.

I also leave a `#warning` for myself to make sure I uncomment before making any commits to my Swift Package.

(It's worth adding that this is in addition to wrapping all test code in `#if !os(watchOS)` conditionals.)